# How to write a fast log-sum-exp in Cython and Weave?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am looking at options to accelerate the log-sum-exp (using the "max trick") operation from Python code. 
I am on Windows 8 using Python 2.7. I have put together a comparison of implementations using Numpy, Scipy's implementation, Numba, Cython, Weave and numexpr, which can be viewed [here on nbviewer](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/285184b4a808dfea7070).

I had expected my Cython and Weave versions to be the fastest of all, as they're nearest to the native code. But in fact, they're slower than my other versions.

How to make these versions as fast as possible ?

*Edit: wrt initial notebook, added max trick in all methods to make comparison less trivial, and nearer to my actual need.*

Comment: Your benchmark of `scipy.misc.logsumexp` is slower than it could be, because you're adding a function call to it. But anyway, it *does* "the max trick" in recent SciPy and is therefore more stable than your other approaches.

Comment: @larsmans Thanks for the hint! Yes, the additional function call seems to take 2-4 µsec. "max trick": indeed, I had seen that, but that's only if you specify the b argument, otherwise it won't do it, cf [first example in doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.logsumexp.html).

Comment: I'm not an expert in this sort of thing, but my understanding is that cython and weave are only helpful if you are defining functions that aren't already implemented in numpy as fast functions.  You're basically just wrapping the three function calls, not eliminating any loops, so it's not surprising that it doesn't speed it up.  Someone please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: In any case, you can shave a tiny bit (10% for me) by using `np.einsum` instead of `np.sum`: `np.log(np.einsum('i->',np.exp(a)))`

Comment: Finally, the 'max trick' seems to be implemented regardless of the value of `b`: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.0/scipy/misc/common.py#L87

Comment: @askewchan re speedup: maybe, but my point is, I didn't expect it to be 3 times slower either: that is the point of my question, really. and in real life, I'd like to include the max-trick (something I cannot reduce to pure numpy calls), and still be fast. re max trick: thanks for proof-by-source-code :-) since it's not comparable to the other implementations, I'll remove it from the comparison.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea why it's _slower_, I presume the added overhead is sufficient, given that the computations are already done in the numpy compiled code.  Perhaps the overhead can be avoided by writing a `lse` with the [c-api](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.html)

Comment: Have you tried using a typed memoryview instead of a numpy array for the input? http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

Comment: @DaveP Typed memoryviews are usually slower, unless I missed some recent development in cython.

Comment: @larsmans - According to the timings given in this blog entry, typed memoryviews can be much faster than numpy arrays: http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/08/memoryview-benchmarks/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An explicitly vectorized (SSE) c version is about 2.5x faster than any of the alternatives that you posted on my machine (~360 us vs 150 us), for float32 data. I don't have numba so I couldn't try that.

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rmcgibbo/logsumexp/blob/master/Accelerating%20log-sum-exp.ipynb

Note, this is only with float32. One of the disadvantages of explicit SSE code is that it's very datatype specific, and I didn't take the effort to write a double precision version.

The full source code for the SSE implementation (BSD), with a simple setup.py installer is at https://github.com/rmcgibbo/logsumexp/tree/master

```
%timeit scipy.misc.logsumexp(a)
10.4467
1000 loops, best of 3: 363 µs per loop
10.4467144498
%timeit lse_weave(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 352 µs per loop
10.4467
%timeit lse_numexpr(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 360 µs per loop
10.4467162773
%timeit lse_cython(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 361 µs per loop
10.4467163086
%timeit sselogsumexp.logsumexp(a)  # <--- my version
10000 loops, best of 3: 149 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will check out. The nbviewer came up again it seems, if you want to give a look.

Comment: @Sebastien, I totally rewrote my answer and actually compared it to the ones you posted (except numba).

Comment: How does numpy.logaddexp compare?